Use RSAT Tools in a Linux Powershell
Is there a way to use the RSAT tools (remote server administration) via powershell on a linux machine? I am specifically interested in the DNS module and users module.
Edit: I am planning to use it against AD joined Windows Server.


Are you planning to use it against Windows Server or against Samba? There are a few options for PowerShell, but the most common one relies on AD WS and won't work against Samba [though I am not sure if it's available on Linux anyway]. 2) Is PowerShell a requirement in general?


ad 2): What do you mean?  Is there another way to edit DNS entries and user/group/OU/etc. entries?

Regarding 2), user management via RSAT goes through LDAP (traditional) – and we also build our custom AD tools using just python-ldap – but the "Get-ADFoo" PowerShell modules use HTTP-based "AD web services" API that modern WinSrv20xx provides (but Samba does not). I suspect the same may be true for DNS, which RSAT manages via MS-RPC (though the DNS data can also be accessed via LDAP), but I wouldn't be surprised if the PowerShell module did otherwise.

The GUI clients probably will not run on Linux. These are basically plugins to the MMC framework built in to Windows computers. But PowerShell is cross platform, and so cmd line interactions are probably very possible, and might not even require installing anything besides PS7 and opening a session to the necessary server.

I don't think that's possible directly, at least not in the way you would do it from a Windows client to a Windows server, since it relies on some of RSAT being installed on the local machine which isn't possible on a Linux box.
Probably your best bet is to look at PS Remoting. Either remoting to the servers directly (if you have access to make the required config changes to the server), or to another Windows device that has the RSAT tools installed on.
Details available here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/security/remoting/ssh-remoting-in-powershell?view=powershell-7.4
Essentially the end result once setup is that when you connect to the Windows machine via Enter-PSSession you're interacting with the remote machine much like you would be if you were directly logged into it (similar to SSHing from a Windows machine into a Linux box using Putty).
